# length of column, split by group

Tags: r, count, bar-chart

Hi I am using R to count the number of datapoints in a column, split by groups like so:

```
Type          Value
----          -----
A             1
A             6
A             4
A             6
B             8
B             10
B             3
B             8 
C             7
C             4
```

where I want to plot 3 bars, how many A's,how many B's, how many C's. The values in the value column are not important.

How do I do this.

If my data were in different columns I could obviously use

```
sapply(list(col1,col2,col3),length))
```

but I don't want to transform my data.

Thanks

Comment: `plot(table(DF[,1]))`

Comment: See first example in `?geom_bar` in package `ggplot2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Value` column doesn't matter, then ggplot2 can help you in that regard

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(9001)
df <- data.frame(Type = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 2)), Value = sample(1:20, 10))
df

##    Type Value
## 1     A     5
## 2     A    19
## 3     A     4
## 4     A    12
## 5     B     1
## 6     B    18
## 7     B    13
## 8     B    17
## 9     C     8
## 10    C    14

ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x = Type))
```

[image: output]